# how to use other encodings with JSON?

Tags: php, javascript, json, encoding

I know that JSON_decode only works with UTF-8, I want to use characters like this:"ë" how can I achieve that? or there is not way?

THANK YOU FOR YOUR TIME AND HELP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just encode the character in UTF-8.  It looks like you want [U+00EB](http://www.charbase.com/00eb-unicode-latin-small-letter-e-with-diaeresis), or as it's called in the Unicode spec: "LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH DIAERESIS".

In UTF-8 that is two bytes: `c3 ab`

Or you can use an string escape: `"\u00eb"`

You should probably also read Joel Spolsky's article [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).